# Getting error incorrect syntax what am i doing wrong

Tags: sql

I am getting an error from this code:

```
DECLARE @New_Hospitalstaff TABLE 
        (
            [NAME] VARCHAR(50),
            JOB VARCHAR(50), 
            HIREDATE DATETIME,
            CITY VARCHAR(50),
            [STATE] VARCHAR(50)
        )

INSERT INTO @New_Hospitalstaff (NAME, JOB, HIREDATE, CITY, STATE)
    SELECT 
        (SUBSTRING(Name, 1, (CHARINDEX('_', Name) - 1,))), AS Name
        (SUBSTRING(JoB, (CHARINDEX('_'job) + 1, 15)) AS JobHireDate,
        (SUBSTRING(Location, 1, (CHARINDEX('_', Location) - 1))) AS City
        (SUBSTRING(Location, CHARINDEX('_', Location) + 1, 10)) AS State 
    FROM 
        DBO.HospitalStaff

SELECT *
FROM @New_Hospitalstaff
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting please?

Comment: If the IDE that you're using doesn't do it for you, consider using something like Notepad++ or Atom to format your queries. Both are free and will alert you at least some of the typos seen in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a lot of syntax errors. I think formatting your code and paying closer attention to parenthesis will help you. Take a look at this and compare to yours.

```
DECLARE @New_Hospitalstaff TABLE ( [NAME] varchar(50) , [JOB] varchar(50) , [HIREDATE] datetime , 
                                   [CITY] varchar(50) , [STATE] varchar(50) )

INSERT INTO @New_Hospitalstaff(NAME,JOB,HIREDATE,CITY,STATE ) 
SELECT (SUBSTRING(Name,1, (CHARINDEX('',Name)-1))) AS Name, 
       -- Missing [JOB] field in query. Needed in order for INSERT to work. 
       -- You probably want the whole field so: JOB, 
       (SUBSTRING(JOB, (CHARINDEX('', job)+1),15)) AS JobHireDate, 
       (SUBSTRING(Location,1, (CHARINDEX('',Location)-1))) As City,
       (SUBSTRING(Location, CHARINDEX('',Location)+1,10)) As State
FROM DBO.HospitalStaff 

SELECT * FROM @New_Hospitalstaff
```

I fixed out of place commas, missing parenthesis, and extra parenthesis based on the functions being called.

Comment: It was kind of you to fix all of the OP's typos. I would note that the re-written query will still throw an error because the number of columns in the `SELECT` list doesn't match the number of columns in the `INSERT` statement. `JOB` is missing.

Comment: @EricBrandt Answer editted to note that missing field. Good catch. I wanted to provide the OP a more functional example so they have something to compare to. Typos aren't always the easiest to see if you're not specifically looking at each character.

Comment: I'll admit to being a little spoiled. I have Redgate SQL Prompt, which highlights the column in the Insert list when you're on a column in the Select list, and vice versa. Which has saved my butt more than once. :)